# How to use <sub> in <img alt="">?

Tags: html, image, alt

Is there any way to use a `<sub>` tag in the `alt` attribute of an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `alt` is plain-text, but you could fake it with [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block), e.g.

```html
<img alt="X₃">
```

See more at [Sitepoint forums](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?818182-subscript-in-alt-attribute).